# white bottom border in fullpage.js

Tags: html, css, browser, fullpage.js

I am using fullpage.js for a website and unfortunately got a small bottom border when the page is loaded (for one section). If I have more than 1 section, the top 10-20px of the background-image of the second section are visible. When I resize the window, the background-image resizes itself and is back to full-screen width and height.

I think it might have something to do with the bottom-left "connection to xy.com is set up" thing from the browser, but I am not sure.

Would be great, if this issue got resolved! Thanks!

Comment: can you show some code and demo?

Comment: No code, no reproduction of it => no answer will be able to help you I'm afraid.

Comment: okay, I just tested it again and narrowed it down to the following: I got a <header> ..</header> on the last slide of the first section, which somehow makes the small bottom border oO

Comment: actually it isn't really a border, it makes the section around 20px smaller and thereby I see the top 20 px of the next section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be related with [this issue opened in fullpage.js issues forum](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/1502).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I solved it with removing

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

from head of page.